# I am a app developer and I am unable access Create Passenger Name Record API

Tags: sabre

I have sent couple of emails to support team for become a sabre customer, I have submitted the application to get the access at following link.

https://www.sabretravelnetwork.com/home/solutions/travel_agency/contract_selector/without_arc2

Pls let us know if I am missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Access to the PNR (Passenger Name Records) requires a contract with Sabre.  They only give this access to travel agents or companies writing services for travel.  There is also associated fees.  Also you need to be aware there are costs for every PNR you create.  So its not as easy as just getting access to the PNR.

I know this is not the answer you want but its how it works.
If your just trying to build out a small booking engine I would suggest getting into Expedia's API toolkit.  Much easier and allot less expensive to get into.